# Twitter Sdk integration in React-native Android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, twitter, react-native-firebase

I am getting error while building the application for android.

> Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1.

build.gradlew looks like this.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Using this package for twitter sign-in using with Social Authentication/react-native-firebase.

react-native-twitter-signin/twitter-signin": "^1.2.0

Comment: The `com.twitter.sdk.android` package has been deprecated (it was retired several years ago) - you should probably talk to the Firebase folks about it.